# Role of parenthesis in a ternary operator expression

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I want to know **what parenthesis exactly doing in following code** (or conditional operator.) :

```
int main(){
    int score = 91;
    cout<<((score>90)? "A grade!" : "Good");
}
```

so the result is "A grade!" (This is what I expected)

---

Without the outermost parenthesis, the return value is 1 , which is not expected for me.

I usually  make additional string object and assign the value from ternary operator If I need it.
Not this way

I treat `()` as noting but indicator of precedence so far..  Is there any Implicit convert function in `()` ?

---

What I expected with follow code : "A grade!"

`cout<<(score>90)? "A grade!" : "Good" ;`

What I really got : 1

What I knew after Googling : I should use parenthesis

What I still don't know : Why shoud I use it? and what exactly parenthesis do

Comment: It's a matter of operator precedence. Without the outer parentheses, you call `operator<<(std::cout, score>90)` which is `operator<<(std::cout, true)` hence the `1`.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `operator <<` has higher precedence that `?:`, so the expression `cout<<(score>90)? "A grade!" : "Good" ;` is interpreted as `(cout << (score>90)) ? "A grade!" : "Good";`

Comment: "I treat () as noting but indicator of precedence so far.. " and it is here. You stopped your line of reasoning to soon and your expectations of what precedence of the involved operators is is off

Comment: Oh, I missed that simple but important point.. Thanks  for kind advice all you guys!

Comment: @GGY - You can also avoid lots of confusion by using a simple if-statement: `if (score > 90) cout << "A grade!"; else ...` The ternary operator is not some magic optimization, but rather a source of confusion.

Comment: i second BoP. There are actual use cases for the ternary, expressions that cannot be replaced by a `if-else`. In all other cases the ternary may safe you some keystrokes but at the expense of readability and simpleness of the code. Remember that code is written once but read many times. The price for typing less is paid back many times when reading code and having to spend more time to figure out what it does

Comment: This is for historical reasons and the (ab)use of the shifting operators for stream extraction and insertion. An operator must always have the same precedence, and given that `1 << 3 ? x : y` was always `(1 << 3) ? x : y` rather than `1 << (3 ? x : y)`, ...